# update data in embeded mongoDB database

Tags: c#, mongodb

hello everyone I create the following database MongoDB I want to update the data in the Array task but I can not do it I wonder if someone can help me here is my code and my database :
[image]

```
        MongoDBHandler h = new MongoDBHandler();
        MongoDatabase database = h._database;
        MongoCollection process = h.process;
        BsonDocument processusImport = new BsonDocument();
        BsonArray tasks = new BsonArray();

        tasks.Add(new BsonDocument
       {
       { "name","validation"},
       { "startDate",""},
       { "endDate",""},
       { "message",""},
       { "status","   "}
       });

        tasks.Add(new BsonDocument
       {
       { "name","GetStockValues"},
       { "startDate",""},
       { "endDate",""},
       { "message",""},
       { "status","   "}
       });

        tasks.Add(new BsonDocument
       {
       { "name","WriteInExcel"},
       { "startDate",""},
       { "endDate",""},
       { "message",""},
       { "status","   "}
       });

        tasks.Add(new BsonDocument
       {
       { "name","CopyToArchive"},
       { "startDate",""},
       { "endDate",""},
       { "message",""},
       { "status","   "}
       });

        tasks.Add(new BsonDocument
       {
       { "name","PrepareUpload"},
       { "startDate",""},
       { "endDate",""},
       { "message",""},
       { "status","   "}
       });

        processusImport.Add("task", tasks);

       processusImport["marque"] = "aaaa";
       processusImport["inputFile"] = "azerty";
       processusImport["processQueue"] =0;
        process.Insert(processusImport);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query for updating, Hope this helps your cause

```
db.Process.update({"task.name":"validation"},{$set:{"task.$.startDate":"someDate","task.$.endDate":"someDate","task.$.message":"someMessage","task.$.status":"someStatus"}})
```

Comment: you never mentioned that you need a c# code in your question, anyways create models i.e classes as per your mongodb structure and using C# mongodb drivers you can update it.